# Website rendering very strange on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, web

I was checking out my website on all platforms to make sure it is displaying properly and it is, except my home page on an iPhone and I cant for the life of me figure out what is going on. I have been using the chrome developer tool and according to it it should be displaying properly, but its really messing up. If anyone with more knowledge can help me figure out whats going on, I would really appreciate it.

website: http://futsoc.co

Answer (score 0):

Same iPhone you checked before this point? If so, you are likely experiencing cache issues.